# Copying a DataRow to a Datatable

Tags: c#

I have a datarow from one table and trying to use that datarow to update the corresponding datarow in another datatable. I know I can loop thru and set each cell but was wondering if there is a sort merge functionality like there is datatables only just the individual datarow

Comment: You have a single row and you want to update multiple rows in the other table? I don't understand this logic. If you want to add this row use `DataTable.ImportRow`, if you want to update one row, search the according row and use `DataRow.SetField` for every field you want to update or assign the new `ItemArray` if you want to update all fields.

Comment: i have one datarow and I want to update a different datatable datarow with that 1st datarow, I know I can loop thru but was wondering if there is a function that acts like the merge only for datarows or is their a linq statement

Comment: If you have primary-keys defined you can use `DataTable.Rows.Find`.

Comment: ok I do but does that update the cells with the other datarow without using a loop

Comment: That  finds the correct row more efficiently but you have to update the field(s) manually (or replace `ItemArray`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the indices of both of the rows you can just set the values of the two data row's item arrays to be equal to one another. For example:

```
DataRow firstTableRow = FirstTable.Rows[YourRow];
DataRow secondTableRow = SecondTable.Rows[YourOtherRow];

secondTableRow.ItemArray = firstTableRow.ItemArray;
```